# Connecting to a Django remote server host

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I ssh-ed into a remote server and ran the command:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The server starts up, development server running at http://0.0.0.0:8000/

Then in my localhost system, I go to the browser and go to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/
```

I'm getting a Problem loading page/Unable to connect error message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to connect to 127.0.0.1, which is your own PC. Substitute it with your server's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use handy shortcut name for your website by adding a record to your `hosts` file:

```
192.168.1.201 mysite.com
```

Where 192.168.1.201 is IP of your dev-server (you should substitute your value), and mysite.com — URL, which will point to your site.

`hosts` file resides in directory C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc (if you are on Windows) or in /etc/ directory on Linux and Mac.